# Class Data Inside Serial Event Handler

Tags: c#, event-handling, serial-port

I know this is really vague but here goes... I am new to Event Handlers and C# Forms so I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. I've created a Serial Port Event Handler and subscribe to the event, as shown below.  I "new" up instances of some classes inside the event handler where I read the serial data and do some parsing. It works just fine.  The form data is globally scoped and persistent and that's all I really need.

But I'm wondering about the hit of creating new instances of my classes every time the event fires.  I know C# does all the housekeeping and I don't see any performance problems firing this thing over and over.  I can't seem to find a way to create new instances of my classes outside the event handler that I can access inside my event handler.  I don't show any of my forms code but it's pretty straight forward.

```
// Create event handler
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    myClass someClass = new myClass();
    // do some work
}

// subscribe to the event
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

Comment: Depending on what your `myClass` does, considering that your event handler is static, you could just have a static singleton object that you reuse. That's probably easiest. But on the other hand, if that class is lightweight and doesn't need to dispose of external resources, there's nothing really wrong with what you're doing either. I suppose with really heavy use, you might run out of space on the heap before the GC can reclaim the memory, but that's an exercise for refactoring at a later date.

Comment: The object sender can be a class which is passes by reference so it is the same object.  So you need to register the event inside the handler every time you get an event and pass the object to the new event.  See readevent at the socket example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example  The serial port example at msdn only will receive one message.

Comment: Well, it depends.  How often does this happen?  How long do these things hang around?  How big are they (and how much work is involved in creating them)?  Are they Disposable?  Do they have Finalizers (aka Destructors)?  If they are expensive to create, you are creating hundreds of them per second and they are short lived, it may make sense for you to manage a bunch of them out of a pool - but that's a lot of work.  If they are cheap to create and they live only a short time, then the GC will very likely do a good job (read up on generational garbage collection)

Comment: thanks everyone.  I've got a little work to do.  most of this is a little over my head right now.